# Postmates API using php/curl - returns unauthorized / Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided

Tags: php, api, curl, postmates

I got myself some postmates customer and api credentials (https://partner.postmates.com/welcome-api)
followed the example here https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3967924/RW1Yq1oN#993c52be-abcc-b06b-3f3d-0abfe9782484 like so

```
$customerId = 'cus_xxxxxxxxxx';
$apiKey = 'aaaaaa-bbbbb-ccc-dddd-eeeeeeee';
$authKey = base64_encode($apiKey.':');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/'.$customerId.'/delivery_quotes',
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('pickup_address' => '76 9th Ave, New York, NY','dropoff_address' => '46 Maujer St, Brooklyn, NY'),
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '.$authKey.'',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
exit();
```

(of course using the actual customerId and apiKey)
but i only ever get as a result the following:

`{"code":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided."}`

(the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false is just added for simplicities sake in a test environment here, using it on a live server with ssl verified yields the same results)
I have of course double and triplechecked the customerid and api key, but the result does not change

If anyone has any idea what i am missing , that would be great as i have been banging my head against the wall for hours now

Comment: The error suggests that you need to authenticate using OAuth2, but you authenticated of the Basic auth scheme.

Comment: Have you tried doing it on the command-line? Once you get results there, its then often obvious how to do it in the PHP code. See `curl(1)`, the postman api-docs already show you how the command is to be build. - Also what @Evert wrote, the api-docs might not show the whole picture, running it on the command-line can reveal this quickly.

Comment: @Evert - i agree that the error suggests that, and I am somewhat puzzled by that as well, but why would it look/ask for oauth2 when the docs say nothing about this and really only talk about Basic auth

Comment: @hakre - I'll give it a go and will report back

Comment: @Olly if you believe that the endpoint _should_ support Basic, and you get this error back then the API is broken / has a bug. Worth reporting to them.

Comment: @hakre - tried on command line : same result

Comment: Then the only thing I see left is really double-checking the api credentials are correct and if so, file a report with the API provider. They should be able to tell you (immediately?).

Comment: @Evert: I am coming to the same conclusion actually as I had this working just fine about a week ago or so, got sidetracked with something else, and after picking up the pieces in the last couple of days do not seem to be able to get past this auth error (though naturally thought it's my end. After all it would not be the first time I messed up somewhere)

Comment: I can confirm that I'm also experiencing this same issue. The documentation made reference to us using basic auth. It was working for me some weeks ago and suddenly stopped working without me making any modifications.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It was working 1 week back. Is there any change in postmates . The php library used is https://github.com/aglipanci/postmates-api . Any suggestion or advice for this ?

Comment: "Any suggestion or advice for this" -

I'd say: write to them - that's about all one can do at this junction i would think. but the more people complain , the more likely it is that someone might do something about this , even if it's just updating the documentation if that is what needs to happen and they really stopped supporting basic auth...

Comment: I suspect this is all caused by Postmates being acquired by Uber recently and now they are trying to somehow merge the 2 API's.
As far as I know the Ueber API does in fact use oAuth2 (according to their docs in any event). 
That said,  getting an Uber developer account to receive the required credentials for their API also appears to be completely impossible currently.